# Android Studio errors with @Override, getException and @NonNull when attempting to add data to Firebase - I need the accurate codes?

Tags: java, android

I am not sure why the below errors are occurring in Android Studio, its not offering any solutions to resolve these errors.  I am attempting to create a budget app and trying to add 'data' to Firebase and its my first attempt, appreciate assistance? My code below:

```
                    Data data = new Data(budgetItem, date, id, null, Integer.parseInt(budgetAmount), months);
                    budgetRef.child(id); 
                    Object setValue; 
                    (data).addOnClickListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()); {
```

Not sure why this is not accepting @Override, @NonNull, isSuccessful and getException

```
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task);
                    {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(BudgetActivity.this, "Budget item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(BudgetActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                            loader.dismiss();
                        }
                    }};
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: You have a semi colon after the listener and after onComplete, so the function is not implemented properly

Comment: Also, an "onCompletelistener" is not an "onClickListener", plus unclear what type of object `data` is, but looks like a regular object which would not have any such method itself

Comment: I removed the semicolon and it produced and error which suggest semicolon 'is expected' which then removes the error when I add it back.

Comment: Also I changed the 'addOnCompleteListener' and 'onCompleteListener' this suggest to create a method in the Data.java file.  This resolved the error but it still insists that it "; expected" at the end.  Thank you for your help other than the semicolon.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the latest code?

Comment: And if your Data class is not a View subclass, there's nothing to click on, so you shouldn't be adding such methods to it

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question with your code, and as a [mcve] rather than out-of-context snippets

Comment: My apologies, I have broken them into three as follows:  All other errors still exist i.e. @Override suggest to be removed

Comment: NonNull suggest options to either be removed, 'Introduce local variable' by 'Edit intention settings, ' Add Clarifying parentheses, Flip '< 'to' >', Negate '< 'to'>'=' or 'Remove unnecessary parentheses'

Comment: .isSuccessful suggest to Rename reference or Remove braces from 'if' statement

Comment: Finally the .getException suggest to Rename reference, Put argument on separate line or Remove braces from 'else' statement - However I have attempted all suggestions, they all produces more errors throughout the code - I'm using Android Studio 4.1.2, has these codes changed? If so what too?

Comment: You still haven't edited your question. I have no idea what you're looking at. Most of the IDE suggestions aren't to fix your syntax problems and assume your syntax is already correct